# Double check a meeting with my professor

Tags: email

I saw my professor couple days ago. He told me we can have meeting on Wednesday. I want to email him to double check the meeting.
Should I say
I just wanted to make sure if we can still have meeting tomorrow? Please let me know if it doesn't work for you anymore.

Comment: When he said _we can have meeting on Wednesday_, did he tell you what time on Wednesday?

Comment: This is not really specific to academia in any way.  You'd send this email to a professor just like you would to anyone else.  Professors aren't some sort of magic beasts that have to be placated with special code phrases.  They are just people.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not specific to academia.

Comment: Does the professor have an administrative assistant? Because they are the ones who often know the prof's timetable better than the prof does. Especially for the more senior professors. Ask the assistant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that sounds like an appropriate email to send anyone if you are ever want to verify that a meeting is going to take place.